# Django circular import

Tags: python, django, python-import

In a django app, in the settings file right at the beginning (before any of the settings have been defined) I have something like this:

```
from myapp.log_filters import add_uid
```

In `myapp.log_filters` I have:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

which I would expect to cause a circular import but somehow it doesn't. Why?

Of course, if I would import the actual setting I need at the beginning instead of using it as `settings.USERID` in the function `add_uid` then I would get an error - which makes sense. So I still don't get why we don't have a circular import error on importing settings from a file that was itself imported by the settings file...

Any links to relevant documentation would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The error was doing from settings import USERID which failed. The explanation you give below is correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short search in the official docs haven't found anything substantive, besides the [following sentence](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code):

> Note that django.conf.settings isn't a module -- it's an object. So importing individual settings is not possible:
>
> ```
> from django.conf.settings import DEBUG  # This won't work.
> ```

This explains why just importing `settings.USEDID` raises an error.

Further browsing [`django`'s source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/__init__.py), I found that `settings` is actually [lazy evaluated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). Here is the relevant code snippet, with some omissions:

```
class LazyObject(object):

    # Avoid infinite recursion when tracing __init__ (#19456).
    _wrapped = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._wrapped = empty

ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE = "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"

class LazySettings(LazyObject):
    def _setup(self, name=None):
        settings_module = os.environ.get(ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
        ...
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if self._wrapped is empty:
            self._setup(name)
        return getattr(self._wrapped, name)

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    def __init__(self, settings_module):
        ...
        # store the settings module in case someone later cares
        self.SETTINGS_MODULE = settings_module

        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
```

Thus an actual import attempt of your specific settings file occurs only when some attribute of `settings` is accessed.
You can easily verify this by running a `pdb` trace, and watching when your module is imported from within `django`.